# Cannot get payload data from jsonwebtoken in node

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) 8.5.1 on a node 10.16.0. My code so far is

```
jwt.sign(
  {  
    role:'role'
  }, 
  key, 
  {  
    issuer:'hey',          
    subject:username,
    expiresIn:Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 604800
  }, 
  function(err, token) {
    if (err) {rejected('token related error');}
    resolved({token:token});  // is inside a promise, so I use resolved/rejected
  }
);
```

At least, this is how I understand it, the first part is the payload that you can include any data you like.

And then my code to verify it

```
jwt.verify(token, key,function(err, decoded) {
  if (err){
    console.log('VERIFY ERROR', err); 
  } 
  if (decoded){ 
    console.log('VERIFY', decoded.role); 
  } 
});
```

When I try to verify it, I dont get any errors, but the `decoded.role` part returns `undefined`, it should return `role`

What am I missing? Please advice

Thanks

Comment: looks fine to me, can't reproduce the error. Check the token you generated in the first part on https://jwt.io and make sure the role is included. On a sidenote: why do you make your token valid until Nov.13th 2070?

Answer (score 0):

It working fine for me:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const key = 'secret';
const username = 'username';

new Promise((resolved, rejected) => {

    jwt.sign(
        {
            role:'role'
        },
        key,
        {
            issuer:'hey',
            subject: username,
            expiresIn:Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 604800
        },
        function(err, token) {
            if (err) {rejected('token related error');}
            resolved({token:token});  // is inside a promise, so I use resolved/rejected
        });
}).then(verify);


function verify({token}) {
    jwt.verify(token, key,function(err, decoded) {
        if (err){
            console.log('VERIFY ERROR', err);
        }
        if (decoded){
            console.log('VERIFY', decoded.role);
        }
    });
}
```

Just make sure you're using the token itself and not the object wrapped around it. As you may have noticed, i am de-structuring the token in the `verify` function like this `{token}`.